# Display Divs by URL, Setting default

Tags: javascript, jquery

For whatever reason my brain isn't functioning this morning and I'm missing something.  I'm displaying divs based on an option value in the URL.  Everything works fine, except for whatever reason with no option set the default isn't working.  I'm getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null" error and it is showing ALL divs.

```
                <div class="single-listing">
                    <div id="info" class="boxes">
                        <h1>DEFAULT BOX</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="checkout" class="boxes">
                        <h1>Checkout</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="recommend" class="boxes">
                        <h1>Recommend Us?</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="recommend-no" class="boxes">
                    </div>

                    <div id="recommend-yes" class="boxes">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is the Javascript.  This is being done within Wordpress so there is a wrapper function for Jquery.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var option = 'info';
                        var url = window.location.href;
                        option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
                        showDiv(option);
                    });
                    function showDiv(option) {
                        $('.boxes').hide();
                        $('#' + option).show();
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure url.match(/option=(.*)/) is not null before accessing an index of the array.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var option = 'info';
        var url = window.location.href;
        var url_option = url.match(/option=(.*)/);
        if (url_option != null)
          option = url_option[1];
        showDiv(option);
    });
    function showDiv(option) {
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('#' + option).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="single-listing">
    <div id="info" class="boxes">
        <h1>DEFAULT BOX</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="checkout" class="boxes">
        <h1>Checkout</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="recommend" class="boxes">
        <h1>Recommend Us?</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="recommend-no" class="boxes">
    </div>

    <div id="recommend-yes" class="boxes">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Glad to help!  Generally good practice to verify you have an array filled with data before trying to access a value in it.

Answer (score 0):

for the default to work you have to have an IF statement in your code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var option = 'info';
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
                    if(option!=null){
                        showDiv(option);
                    }
                    else{
                        showDiv('info');
                    }
                });
                function showDiv(option) {
                    $('.boxes').hide();
                    $('#' + option).show();
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Though even with this fix, you will encounter this error whenever the option parameter is absent. That might be your intention or not.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't resolve it for me.  The 1 is the correct selector for my setup.  Thanks for the response though!

Comment: see my latest edit - you have to say what the default is to be if the regex of the parameter is null